# Summation of finite trigonometric series

Tags: trigonometric-series

Find a closed form for ${\displaystyle \sin(a)+\sin(a+b)+\sin(a+2b)+\cdots +\sin(a+(n-1)b)}$ .

Method 1Edit

To sum the series

${\displaystyle \sin(a)+\sin(a+b)+\sin(a+2b)+\cdots +\sin(a+(n-1)b)=S}$ .

Multiply each term by (this is my question)

${\displaystyle 2\sin \left({\tfrac {b}{2}}\right)}$. (Why multiply with this term.)

Then we have

${\displaystyle 2\sin(a)\sin \left({\tfrac {b}{2}}\right)=\cos \left(a-{\tfrac {b}{2}}\right)-\cos \left(a+{\tfrac {b}{2}}\right)}$

and similarly for all terms to

${\displaystyle 2\sin {\bigl (}a+(n-1)b{\bigr )}\sin \left({\tfrac {b}{2}}\right)=\cos \left(a+{\tfrac {(2n-3)b}{2}}\right)-\cos \left(a+{\tfrac {(2n-1)b}{2}}\right)}$ .

Summing, we find that nearly all the terms cancel out and we are left with

${\displaystyle 2S\sin \left({\tfrac {b}{2}}\right)=\cos \left(a-{\tfrac {b}{2}}\right)-\cos \left(a+{\tfrac {(2n-1)b}{2}}\right)=2\sin \left(a+{\tfrac {(n-1)b}{2}}\right)\sin \left({\tfrac {nb}{2}}\right)}$ .

Hence

${\displaystyle S=\sin \left(a+{\tfrac {(n-1)b}{2}}\right){\frac {\sin \left({\tfrac {nb}{2}}\right)}{\sin \left({\tfrac {b}{2}}\right)}}}$ .

Similarly, if

${\displaystyle C=\cos(a)+\cos(a+b)+\cos(a+2b)+\cdots +\cos {\bigl (}a+(n-1)b{\bigr )}}$

then

${\displaystyle C=\cos \left(a+{\tfrac {(n-1)b}{2}}\right)\cdot {\frac {\sin \left({\tfrac {nb}{2}}\right)}{\sin \left({\tfrac {b}{2}}\right)}}}$

Why multiple both terms with 2sin b/2

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Plz why was 2sin b/2 used to multiple the terms.

Comment: You mean how the idea came to somebody to multiply  by $2 \sin b/2$ ? In fact, the discovery can come from people very able at trigonometric formulas but it is much simpler to explain it with complex numbers summations (see the solution by Mark Viola in the reference given to you by Blue)

Comment: Yes but that complex numbers is quite complex for me.